# Switching To Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation

everyone i am newto these linux stuffs. Currently i'm a user of Windows8.1 .
When windows 8 was roling out i was like i'm never going to leave and will be always
stick to windows8 but now i think it's time to switch linux because being in windows
forever i don't think i can do something very good .I wanted to be OpenSource :) . 
So i really dont have any idea about linux . For me the best distro is Ubuntu and 
Kubuntu offcourse the latest release . So what i'm afraid of switching to linux is 
its compability .The compatibility i'm talking about is with the hardware's and driver's
. For eg sometime after fresh install of windows we need to install the display,usb and 
wifi drivers to function . For some computer or brands those driver's are hard to find
and i can't even think of linux how hard are they to find if it needs installing drivers.
So my main question is that do i need to install the drivers for my wifi adapters 
display and some other stuffs or the distro i choosed i.e Ubuntu 14.0.4 consists of
those dirvers and what about the 64 and 32bit . My machines is 64bit aso do i need to 
install the 64bit one . I mean i know the advantages of installing the 64 bit one but
like windows is it kinda hard to find softwares for the 64 bit one . Or the 32 bit is 
recommended . And Yes I will be highly appreciated for the answers to my questions . 
Thank You :)

Comment: Download the 64 bit ISO which is both an installer and live mode system and install to a flash drive. Instructions in link. Then boot it in live mode and see if it works. Some do have video issue and need boot settings, so testing helps know if you have issues. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download Note that Linux is not Windows. While you can do most things users want to do, you cannot run most Windows applications. A few run in Wine, even many of those do not work 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . My main question is that do i need additional wifi drivers and video drivers to work or do my wifi works automatically after the fresh install of 14.0.4 one :)

Comment: You can know that for sure once you test it out. For starters I'd recommend dual booting both Windows and Linux and then later you can dumb Windows completely. Linux is an adventure, try it out, if something doesn't work, we are here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu by default supports many peripheral devices. If any problem persist while  configuring, you can post your  problem in this forum. Many will guide you.

I will strongly suggest you to install a 32 bit from my side.
Usually i download software from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os%3Alinux/) and many softwares are developed to work in 32 bit environment only.

however it totally depends upon how you are going to use it.

> Kindly visit http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu before installing.

Answer (score 1):

As long as windows does not provide support for more than one machine. So, my other machine is linux and at the begining it was frustrating but time has changed, and nearly all driver is supporting now. For printer HP is best support, for graphics card my Nvidia is working ok with Nvidia driver, wired and wireless modem, camera also working etc. I recommend 64bit for more than 4gb ram. My ubuntu is 64bit. On the other hand my Epson printer not working properly, etc. Though software centre saves time as it install app without any headache to copy and paste command.  linux is awsome and now it is not frustrating for me.

Comment: My RAM is 4GB and since i have not yet used the 32bit one i would like to use the 64 bit in here too but due to the compatibility issue i'm scared so i want to try it out first and if everythings worked i'm gonna use it as the Primary Os .Anyway Thanks for the quick replies .

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu,  especially 14.04 You shouldn't have drivers problem.  I've  install Ubuntu  on many hardware Configurations,  and I remember,  that only on hp Pavilion dv6710ew was problem with network card (erhernet),  and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of your guys for quick and sweet replies . I just tried Ubuntu14.04 in my laptop and dekstop . I love them and i'm soon migrating to Ubuntu making it as primary OS . :)